# Random Forest and Cross Validation

Tags: random-forest

If I use cross-validation for the training and evaluation of a Random Forest model, do I NOT bag the data?

If cross validation is used and not bagging (assuming this is a correct approach), are the trees in the forest constructed using one fold at a time per forest construction (bagging is done prior to the construction of each tree in the forest)?

CV performance is determined by taking the average of the fold results.  How is the final model determined?  The forest constructed from each fold will be different.  Which forest (or combination of forests) is used for predictions?

Comment: That's a lot of questions at once.

Comment: 1. You do bag the data for each training data set (there will be K of them if you do K-fold cross-validation.)  2. Not relevant, given the answer to 1.  3.  The final model is built on all the data at once, not on a combination of the fold-specific models.

Comment: @jbowman:  Don't you bag prior to creation of each tree in each fold (so # of bags/fold = #trees in fold?)

Comment: Yes, you do, but your question appears to be more about whether you bag at all, not  how it's done.  With cross-validation, each fold is treated just as if it were the entire problem; if it weren't, that would at best weaken and at worse ruin your ability to learn anything from the procedure.